# Javascript Sleep Function in For, While

Tags: javascript

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
//codes
sleep(500);
}
```

This code working finely with php , how to write this code with js ? help me please

Comment: Look into `setTimeout()`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout check here for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the `setTimeOut()` function. Here's how the basic usage goes :

```
setTimeOut(function(){ /*Your code */},500);
```

Also note that the time is in milliseconds.
[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) are some more examples to help you.